# an array of structs?

Tags: c, string, struct

I am trying to write up a string container for my string struct but it's not working.  I feel like I've been showing everyone my code and expecting a simple answer to get me going but what I'd like is a tip or a few pointers to get me going.  Right now I don't want this container to be able to hold anything else except a custom *string* that I wrote earlier, which is working fine by the way.

All the code is a simplified version of my real string struct because there's no need to post it; all we're dealing with is the string container.

**header.h**

```
typedef struct string string;
```

**source.c**

```
struct string {
    char *buffer;
    unsigned int size;
};
```

*Would I do:*

```
string ** array_of_strings;
```

*or*

```
string * array_of_strings;
```

*then I want to do something like:*

**client.c**

```
array_of_strings = (string *) malloc(0);
```

When I call `malloc(0)`, I am wanting there to be `array_of_strings[0]`
and if I `realloc(1)` I would like it to be `array_of_strings[1]`.

Is there a better way to do this, because this isn't working?

Comment: `malloc(0)` will allocate 0 bytes of memory.

Comment: When you say `malloc(0)` you are saying: "Allocate 0 bytes of space on the heap." You want to allocate at least sizeof(string). You also want to allocate the buffer that the string struct points to.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575921/array-of-structs-in-c

Comment: You cannot use the standard `malloc()` and `realloc()` functions as you show; you could write your own with the non-standard semantics you request (but you would have to use different names, such as `str_malloc()` and `str_realloc()`).  Note that names starting with `str` and a lower-case letter are reserved for future extensions of the standard C library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an array of one string, you should allocate memory for one string:

```
string * array_of_strings;
array_of_strings = malloc(sizeof(string));
```

and then you may access `array_of_strings[0]`.

If you will declare it as `string **` you actually declare a pointer to pointer to `string`, not a pointer to `string`.

Comment: how would i realloc and be able to access array_of_strings[1]?

Comment: `array_of_strings = realloc(sizeof(string)*2);`

Comment: what if im doing
        char *string = (char*) malloc(strlen(string) + 1)
am i reserving bytes or array slots?

Comment: I does not fit to the struct at all.

Comment: btw when i use my string struct it has to be a pointer does that mean i use 2 pointers or still use 1 like mbyd said to?  i need an array of pointer structs

Comment: You cannot do `strlen(string)` because `string` is a type name and not a variable name.  Besides, you do not need to use `strlen()`; you know how long the string is from the structure:  `string *str; ...initialize...; unsigned len = str->size;`.