# How can I make a struct array [30]?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Hello I'm a bit confused about struct arrays...

How can I make an array with this struct:

```
struct m_StudentData
{
    char Sex, Class [10];
    char Phone [15];
    char Name, Surname, Nationality [30];
    char Rooms, Subjects, Mail [64];
    CString Information, Address;
    CDateTimeCtrl Birthday;
}
```

Comment: `m_StudentData studentArr[30];`

Comment: Be careful, m_StudentData is a type name, I have met the naming with the prefix 'm_' to members (like `Sex` or `Address`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make an array of structs in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468128/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

simple, just use the struct as type

```
struct m_StudentData
{
    char Sex, Class [10];
    char Phone [15];
    char Name, Surname, Nationality [30];
    char Rooms, Subjects, Mail [64];
    CString Information, Address;
    CDateTimeCtrl Birthday;
};

m_StudentData arr[30];
```

Comment: thx for your answer but now I get this error: expected a declaration

Comment: Add semi-colon at the end of your struct declaration. Also, don't use `memset` with this class, as it is not POD.

Comment: You need to define the struct before main, or declare it before main, or in a header that you include. (and, as mentioned, you have forgotten the `;` after the struct's last `}`)

Comment: Add semicolon at the end, edited my earlier ans

Comment: @DebasishJana Let's wait for the next question in a comment _But now I get an error in (something totally unrelated) ..._ ;)

Comment: hahahah yeah I got some other errors but I think its because I made the struct array in an additional header file. So I think I have to declare it in another file?

Comment: declare the struct in header file and the array (if global) must be in some implementation file (.c, or .cpp whatever you have)