# have a loop to create structs

Tags: c#, c, struct

i wanna make a callLog with struct in C# 
so i remember in C we had such a thing:

```
struct contact
{
string name;
string phone;
}contact_q[200]
```

and for filling the contacts's information we had such a thing:

```
while(i<200)
{
 scanf("%s",student_q[i].name)
}
```

so in C# we don't have that declaration:"contact-q[200]" at the end of struct
and i could not handle a loop for filling name and phone because we don't have such a thing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Contacts contact[i]=new Contacts();
            }
```

it has error with : contact[i]

so help me

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx

Comment: You have to declare array before for loop : Contacts[] contact = new Contacts(10);

Answer (score 1):

For a solution in C# you've been really close to the correct syntax. The problematic part in your attempt was the assignment in the loop.

Do the following and your code should compile and work:

```
Contacts[] contacts = new Contacts[10];
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.Length; i++)
{
     contacts[i] = new Contacts();
}
```

Please note that the name of your struct (`Contacts`) is somewhat unfortunate. It represents a single contact but its name implies it'd contain multiple contact**s**. So, I'd rename you C#-struct from `Contacts` to `Contact` (as you have done in your C++ sample, too).

Comment: @Navid If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

In C# first declare the array

```
 fixed Contacts contact[10];  // fixed array
```

or

```
 Contacts contract[] = new Contracts[10];  // dynamic array
```

then in the loop

```
 contact[i]=new Contacts();
```

---

Your memory of C is slightly wrong BTW it was actually

```
typedef struct contact
{
  string name;
  string phone;
} contact_q[200]
```

The typedef is important -- is is creating a type (contact_q)

Comment: would u plz explain more?

Comment: @Navid -- nothing to explain, this is how you declare and use arrays in C++  Look at any basic C++ textbook on arrays.

Comment: i tried it but is has error here : Contacts contact[10];

Comment: errors:Error 4 Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type. C:\Users\NAVID-PC\Desktop\CallLog\CallLog\Program.cs 20 24 CallLog

Comment: Error 5 Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression) C:\Users\NAVID-PC\Desktop\CallLog\CallLog\Program.cs 20 25 CallLog

Comment: @Hogan I think you mean C#, not C++ in your first comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza - yes I did.

Comment: Just to be clear: The C `typedef` declares the *type* `contact_q` to be an ***array*** of 200 `struct contact`. It does *not* define any variable. This is different form the OP's snippet which defines `contact_q` to actually *be* the array *variable*.

Comment: @alk I was under the impression the OP was saying the struct snippet was C code not C# code.

Comment: I am as well referering to C only, to your C snippet, as well as the OP's.

Comment: @alk -- oh I see.. you are explaining how C and C# are different.  Of course you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of `struct`s.
What probably works is

```
struct contact {
  string name;
  string phone;
}

struct contact contact_q[200];
```

and then simply assigning

```
contact_q[i].name=...
```

or with your `while` loop.
You can also `typedef`:

```
typedef struct contact {
  string name;
  string phone;
} contact_it;

contact_it contact_q[200];
```

See, e.g.,

[How do you make an array of structs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468128/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

Comment: This is not C# -- the OP is asking about C#

Comment: what should i do in C#?