# Creating an array from a text file to call each line individually

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've looked at multiple other similar questions but none of them worked with my code, and I gave up trying to look things up.

I'm trying to create a program that takes each line, which has a book title, from a file into a character array, because I need to call each book later, so book[1], book[2], etc. However, I cannot figure out how to create the array with my struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define Num_Book 9

typedef struct book {
  char *book_name;
  size_t length;
  ssize_t title;
}BOOK;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  BOOK *Book;
  Book = (BOOK *) malloc (sizeof(BOOK));

  (*Book).book_name = NULL;
  (*Book).length = 0;
  char title_arr[Num_Book][50]; 
  //this is the array that I tried creating, 
  //but it kept giving me warnings when I tried to compile

//opening my file
FILE *f_books;
f_books = fopen("books.txt", "r");

if (f_books == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file for reading.\n");
}
printf("Book list\n");

while (((*Book).title = getline(&(*Book).book_name, &(*Book).length, f_books)) != -1)
{
    printf("%s", (*Book).book_name);
}
```

If anyone has any ideas, it is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468128/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-structs-in-c

Comment: Why is the `ssize_t title;` element present?  You don't use it or initialize it, which is worrying.  Do you have any idea how many books you'll have to process?  Can you pre-allocate an array of `BOOK` structures, or do you need to do it manually (dynamically) with `malloc()` et al?

Comment: `Book = (BOOK *) malloc (sizeof(BOOK));` will not create any space for the book_name field of the BOOK struct.  You will need to read the string from the file into a buffer first, and then allocate space for the book_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to declare an array of structs in `main()`, using the `Num_Book` macro that you defined in the preprocessor directives. Since you are using `getline()`, you do not even need to manually allocate memory to store the strings; instead you can let the `getline()` function do the work. Note that `getline()` is not a Standard C function, but it is POSIX, and also a GNU extension. On some systems you may need to enable this function using a feature test macro, which is included in the code below.

To take advantage of the automatic memory allocation capability of `getline()`, you need to pass in a null pointer for the first argument, and the second argument should be a pointer to a `size_t` variable containing a value of zero.

In the loop that reads the data into the structs, temporary variables are used instead of directly assigning to the struct fields. This allows the current string to be inspected before the final assignment, so that empty lines are not stored as book records.

Remember that `getline()` keeps the `\n` character, so if the current line is non-empty, the terminating newline is replaced with a `\0` terminator. Then the values held by the temporary variables are assigned to the appropriate fields of the current `BOOK struct`, `temp_name` and `temp_length` are reset to `NULL` and `0`, and `i` is incremented.

You still need to free memory allocated by `getline()`, so this should be done before ending the program.

Note that in the original code, while you were checking to be certain that the file `books.txt` was successfully opened, you did not `exit()` here. This would lead to problems in the event that the file failed to open, when the program went on as if it had opened. You could handle the error differently; for example, it may be appropriate to instead ask the user for a different filename.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define Num_Book  9

typedef struct book {
    char *book_name;
    size_t length;
    ssize_t title;
} BOOK;

int main(void)
{
    BOOK books[Num_Book];

    FILE *f_books;
    f_books = fopen("books.txt", "r");

    if (f_books == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file for reading.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Book list\n");

    char *temp_name = NULL;
    size_t temp_length = 0;
    ssize_t temp_title;
    char *find;
    size_t i = 0;
    while ((temp_title = getline(&temp_name, &temp_length, f_books))
           != -1 && temp_name[0] != '\n') {

        /* Replace newline with '\0' */
        if ((find = strchr(temp_name, '\n')) != NULL) {
            *find = '\0';
        }

        books[i].book_name = temp_name;
        books[i].length = temp_length;
        books[i].title = temp_title;
        temp_name = NULL;
        temp_length = 0;

        printf("%s\n", books[i].book_name);
        ++i;
    }

    /* Still need to free allocated memory */
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(books[j].book_name);
    }
    if (temp_name) {
        free(temp_name);
    }

    if (fclose(f_books) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Book list
The Sound and the Fury
So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish
Gargantua and Pantagruel
Foundation
```

If you need to dynamically allocate space for the books, you can modify the above code. Below is a version that does this, first by initializing a variable `max_books` to a reasonable starting value. Space is allocated and assigned to a pointer to `BOOK`, and when a new book is added the space is reallocated if necessary.

After all books have been added, the allocation can be trimmed to exact size. Note the use of identifiers instead of explicit types in the `sizeof` arguments. This is less error-prone and easier to maintain if types change in future iterations of the code. Also note that `realloc()` will return a null pointer in the event of an allocation error. Here, direct assignment to `books` would result in the loss of previously stored data, and a memory leak. For this reason, the address of the new allocation is first stored in `temp`; the value of `temp` is assigned to `books` only if it is not `NULL`.

The same allocations must be freed as before, but in addition, the dynamically allocated array must also be freed.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct book {
    char *book_name;
    size_t length;
    ssize_t title;
} BOOK;

int main(void)
{


    FILE *f_books;
    f_books = fopen("books.txt", "r");

    if (f_books == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file for reading.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *temp_name = NULL;
    size_t temp_length = 0;
    ssize_t temp_title;
    char *find;
    size_t i = 0;
    BOOK *books;
    BOOK *temp;
    size_t max_books = 10;
    size_t num_books = 0;

    if ((books = malloc((sizeof *books) * max_books)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate books\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((temp_title = getline(&temp_name, &temp_length, f_books))
           != -1 && temp_name[0] != '\n') {

        ++num_books;

        /* Replace newline with '\0' */
        if ((find = strchr(temp_name, '\n')) != NULL) {
            *find = '\0';
        }

        /* Reallocate books if more space is needed */
        if (num_books == max_books) {
            max_books *= 2;
            if ((temp = realloc(books, (sizeof *books) * max_books)) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reallocate books\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            books = temp;
        }

        /* Store book data */
        books[i].book_name = temp_name;
        books[i].length = temp_length;
        books[i].title = temp_title;
        temp_name = NULL;
        temp_length = 0;

        ++i;
    }

    /* If you need books to be trimmed to minimum size */
    if ((temp = realloc(books, (sizeof *books) * num_books)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to trim books allocation\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    books = temp;

    /* Display list of books */
    printf("Book list\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_books; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", books[i].book_name);
    }

    /* Still need to free allocated memory */
    for (i = 0; i < num_books; i++) {
        free(books[i].book_name);
    }
    free(books);
    if (temp_name) {
        free(temp_name);
    }

    if (fclose(f_books) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I closed the book at the end, but forgot to add that in from my copy and pasted code, but this was really helpful!

Comment: If i'm not sure about the specific number of books, and need to use getline to figure out how many books i have, how can I use this so that I can still call '(printf("%s\n", books[i].book_name);' outside of the while loop

Comment: @Wheeeeeecode-- I added a version that uses dynamic allocation. It keeps track of the number of books stored and prints the results outside of the read loop.