# Creating an Array of Structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In trying to solve this problem, I've been copying the example given in this question [How do you make an array of structs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468128/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-structs-in-c)
So now my code looks like this:

```
#define NUM_TRACES 6

typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t upstream_pin;
    uint32_t dnstream_pin;
    uint32_t led_pin;
}trace;

struct trace traces[NUM_TRACES];

traces[0] = {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0};
traces[1] = {GPIO_Pin_4, GPIO_Pin_6 , GPIO_Pin_1};
```

But I get the following errors

```
src/hal.c:17:14: error: array type has incomplete element type
 struct trace traces[NUM_TRACES];
              ^
src/hal.c:19:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 traces[0] = {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0};
```

I can sort of fix the first error by making the array be an array of pointers to trace structs which I think makes sense

```
struct trace* traces[NUM_TRACES];
```

but then these lines give an error

```
src/hal.c:19:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 traces[0] = {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0};
 ^
src/hal.c:19:1: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'traces'
src/hal.c:19:1: error: conflicting types for 'traces'
src/hal.c:17:15: note: previous declaration of 'traces' was here
 struct trace* traces[NUM_TRACES];
               ^
src/hal.c:19:1: warning: excess elements in array initializer
 traces[0] = {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0};
 ^
```

Which I think is caused by trace[0] actually being a place to store the address of the data, not a place to store the data? But I don't know how to correct this and place the data where I want it in array.

Comment: `typedef struct {...} foo` => `foo something`, or `struct foo {...}` => `struct foo something`. First declares `foo` as an alias for an anonymous struct. Second declares a named `struct foo`. Don't mix.

Comment: Can you post your entire code?

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum.  If you now want to ask about a different issue with the same code, then post it as a new question -- do not edit your question to something altogether different, especially after receiving answers.

Comment: Rolled back. You are supposed not to change the question once you got an answer. This is not a life-editing site

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That's what rollback is for.

Comment: I considered it, @Olaf, but I always hesitate to roll back OP edits.  His did need to be rolled back, but I had hoped to encourage him to do it himself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I hardly see this happen, exspecially because most "newbies" are not even aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your struct as

```
struct trace
{
    …
};
```

The problem with your existing code is you've defined an anonymous struct and a typedef for `trace` that refers to that struct. This means there is no type `struct trace`, so your line `struct trace traces[NUM_TRACES]` is referring to a non-existant type.

You could also define your struct as

```
typedef struct trace
{
    …
} trace;
```

if you want, which would give you both `trace` and `struct trace`, but there's not really any point.

And of course you could keep your current type and just say `trace traces[NUM_TRACES]` instead.

---

Your line of code `traces[0] = {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0 };` is also incorrect. The compiler is interpreting this as a declaration of a zero-length array without a type. If you want to initialize the `traces` array you must do it in an actual initializer, as in

```
struct trace traces[NUM_TRACES] = { {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0} };
```

(if `NUM_TRACES` is greater than `1` this will leave the rest of the array zero-initialized)

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense, I've fixed the struct declaration I think, but I'm still getting the same errors, is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @Indigo Is your code sample exactly as written? It looks like you're saying `traces[0] = {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0 };` at the top level, but you can't write that at the top level, because that's a line of code, not a declaration. The errors you're getting are the compiler insisting on trying to interpret it as a declaration (of a zero-length array) without a type.

Comment: @Indigo Instead you can say something like `struct trace traces[NUM_TRACES] = { {GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_7 , GPIO_Pin_0} };` This should leave all entries past the first one as zeroes.

Comment: Oh, wow, I think I've been writing too much python lately. Your last comment worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a type `struct trace` for which you have not provided a definition.  You can do some things with such a structure type, but not anything that requires the system to know the size or members.

What you *did* define was a tagless structure type, aliased by type name `trace`.  Because it is tagless, that type can only be referenced via the defined alias:

```
/* no struct */ trace traces[NUM_TRACES];
```

Alternatively, you could use your original array declaration if you in fact declared a structure type with tag `trace`:

```
struct trace
{
    uint32_t upstream_pin;
    uint32_t dnstream_pin;
    uint32_t led_pin;
} /* no instances declared here in this case */ ;
```

Note in particular that you do not need `typedef` to declare a structure type; its purpose is to declare type name aliases.  You could, however, define a tagged structure type and an alias for it in one go, so that you could refer to it either with or without the `struct` keyword:

```
typedef struct trace
{
    uint32_t upstream_pin;
    uint32_t dnstream_pin;
    uint32_t led_pin;
} trace ;
```

I don't really recommend that, though -- it is stylistically better to choose one form to use (`struct <tag>` or `aliased_type_name`), and stick with it.