# C Replacing Variable Number

Tags: c

Is it possible to automate this program more in order to change the variable number?

```
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
    printf("Enter the Code for Item #%d: ",i);
    scanf("%d", &CodeNumber1);
    printf("Enter the Price for Item #%d: ",i);
    scanf("%f", &Price1);
    printf("Enter the Quantity for Item #%d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &Quantity1);
    }
```

So where the variable has 1 written, would it be possible to replace it with i?

Without using an array

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468128/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-structs-in-c

Comment: I'd say no. What are you trying to achieve. This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What's wrong with using an array? You definitely need one here.

Comment: Normally the 1 should be replaced by `[i]` or similar, but for some secret reason you don't want to use arrays.

Comment: I wanted to see if it'd be possible doing it without an array, thanks though guys, il use an array

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an array? Challenge accepted. Good thing [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) also works with C!

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

#define LOOP_BODY(z, n, data) \
    printf("Enter the Code for Item #%d: ", n); \
    scanf("%d", &BOOST_PP_CAT(CodeNumber, n)); \
    printf("Enter the Price for Item #%d: ", n); \
    scanf("%f", &BOOST_PP_CAT(Price, n)); \
    printf("Enter the Quantity for Item #%d: ", n); \
    scanf("%d", &BOOST_PP_CAT(Quantity, n));

BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, 4, LOOP_BODY, ~)
```

I am not to be held responsible for any loss of personal or professional reputation, pride, life, limb; or the happenstance of any kind of apocalypse resulting from the use of the code above.

Comment: I am not responsible for any loss of SO reputation either :)

Comment: @Quentin OK, I ignored that. Thanks.

Comment: This is the only answer that directly achieves what the OP wanted!  :)

Comment: Nice. Although you might want to mention that the boost preprocessor is guaranteed to work in C.

Comment: @Bathsheba well, I'm not sure why people believe otherwise. The first line of the documentation is *"The Boost Preprocessing library is a library of macros, with support for preprocessor metaprogramming. The library supports both C++ and C compilation."*

Comment: @Quentin: Well, when old cats like me see a `hpp`, we think C++ header. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Bathsheba added note for old cats.

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing haha

Answer (score 3):

You could use arrays instead of a fix name.
For example you could use something like

```
int CodeNumber[4] = {0};
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the Code for Item #%d: ",i);
    scanf("%d", &CodeNumber[i]);
}
```

In my opinion an even better approach would be to use structs that hold your 3 integers inside:

```
struct item {
  int CodeNumber;
  int ...
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
struct item myItem[4];
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the Code for Item #%d: ",i);
    scanf("%d", &(myItem[i].CodeNumber));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array to hold your variables, like so :

```
int data[4] = {0};
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("Enter the data for item #%d: ",i);
    scanf("%d", &data[i]);
}
```